# how publish and view mvc website basic steps

Tags: asp.net-mvc

First time I am trying to publish an mvc website.  So far I have published it to a local folder and using IIS I have made the folder a virtual folder.  How do I run the website from my browser and how to start it with Account/LogOn?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link of Video tutorial release by ScottGu regarding MVC deployment and study hope this will help you

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/15/great-free-video-training-on-asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many [articles](http://css.dzone.com/news/deploying-aspnet-mvc-web-appli) and [tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs) out there about deploying ASP.NET MVC applications. Once IIS is configured you simply point your browser to `http://localhost/NameOfTheApp/Home/Index` and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

First which version is there on remote server. For your account logon i am assuming that you are using default membership provider. I normally include membership provider table in my database. If you are running on IIS 6.0 then you have to made some changes as mentioned by Haacked on his blog. While publishing make sure that mvc dll in made copy local and is there on your bin folder on remote site. First publish the site on local and if it is running properly upload it on remote server set the connectionstring as told by your hosting provider